# Which react-admin component should I use for the column like Post.className from ra-data-parse?

Tags: parse-platform, react-admin

I have an object called **Post** and an object called **Comment** in parse-server database. **Comment** have a reference field called **Post** point to **Post** object. I use **ListGuesser** :

```
<Resource name="Comment" list={ListGuesser} />
```

Got this in browser console:

```
export const CommentList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <DateField source="createdAt" />
            <DateField source="updatedAt" />
            <TextField source="content" />
            <NumberField source="likes" />
            <TextField source="owner" />
            <TextField source="post.className" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

It shows the **post** field in **Comment** as a **TextField**. Apparently it's not true. How can I get the reference object and show a link in react-admin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<ReferenceField>` for relations. Here you will find explanation:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencefield